# How to make placeholder go to a small label on top left corner when the input field is active?

Tags: html, css, reactjs, animation, input

I have tried to find working code, but they don't work. Is there anybody here that knows how to do this animation in react?

Answer (score -1):

You can use [Material Design](https://m2.material.io/develop/web/getting-started). Let me explain:

First, let's load the library with writing this code in our head tag:

```
<link href="https://unpkg.com/material-components-web@latest/dist/material-components-web.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
<script src="https://unpkg.com/material-components-web@latest/dist/material-components-web.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/icon?family=Material+Icons">
```

Now in our body tag we add a textfield with the options we want:

```
<label class="mdc-text-field mdc-text-field--filled">
    <span class="mdc-text-field__ripple"></span>
    <span class="mdc-floating-label" id="my-label-id">Hint text</span>
    <input class="mdc-text-field__input" type="text" aria-labelledby="my-label-id">
    <span class="mdc-line-ripple"></span>
</label>
```

Finally, we add a script to initial the styles that we want:

```
<script>
    const textField = new mdc.textField.MDCTextField(document.querySelector('.mdc-text-field'));
</script>
```

Be sure to add the script to end of our body tag.

You can see all the other components that you can use [here](https://m2.material.io/components?platform=web).

Although there is a better practice, but this must do the job well enough.